# group indexes that have at least 2 common element in a cell of row vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, row

I am new to Matlab, and I really would appreciate some help

I have

```
A size{6602,1} = 

[107;302;306;601;1014;1014;6016;6016;6016]
26x1 double
26x1 double
[1016;1019;6014]
69x1 double
[201;201;301;301;301;1012;1015]
1013
[301;406;507;508;1014;1016;5011;6014]
401
```

..... and so on

I want to group indexes that have X common elements ( my first iteration I will start with 2 common elements, second iteration with 8 common elements and so on)

this is an example of the data:
[screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRzHh.png)
the result am looking for is : 222,229 or value in colum2(164802771,167884647)

example of data that shows three rows sharing three values [image: snapshot2]
result : 3 1 8 16 .. where 3 is number of shared values and the rest are the row numbers

thanks in advance

Comment: Highlighted output as source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a vectorized solution for you, which may or may not be the most efficient depending on how many unique elements there are in column 1 and how often they appear in different rows. I'll use this simple 6-row example taken from your question:

```
A = {[107; 302; 306; 601; 1014; 1014; 6016; 6016; 6016]; ...
     [1016; 1019; 6014]; ...
     [201; 201; 301; 301; 301; 1012; 1015]; ...
     1013; ...
     [301; 406; 507; 508; 1014; 1016; 5011; 6014]; ...
     401};
```

We'll start by using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to find the unique numeric values that occur across all the cells in `A`:

```
uniqueValues = unique(vertcat(A{:}));
```

Next we can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find, for each unique value, which rows it occurs in:

```
memberIndex = cellfun(@(c) {ismember(uniqueValues, c)}, A);
memberIndex = [memberIndex{:}];

memberIndex =

  19×6 logical array

   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   1   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0
   1   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0   1   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

For `memberIndex` the number of rows is the number of unique values and the number of columns is the number of rows in `A`. The first unique value only appears in row 1, the second unique value only appears in row 3, etc. Notice that a lot of the values only appear in one row of `A`, and since you're looking for elements that are common to multiple rows, we can remove those from the analysis like so:

```
repeatedIndex = (sum(memberIndex, 2) > 1);
uniqueValues = uniqueValues(repeatedIndex)

uniqueValues =

         301
        1014
        1016
        6014

memberIndex = memberIndex(repeatedIndex, :);

memberIndex =

  4×6 logical array

   0   0   1   0   1   0
   1   0   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0   1   0
```

Notice that there are only 4 values that show up in multiple rows of `A` for this example.

Now, here's where things get tricky. Notice that if we take any pair of columns from `memberIndex` above, multiply them element-by-element, and sum the result, we will get the total count of common elements between them. This *could* be done for all combinations of columns with this one matrix multiply:

```
counts = (memberIndex.')*memberIndex;
```

However, the example problem only has 6 rows, whereas your actual data has over 6,000. This would make `counts` an **enormous** matrix, which would be a big memory and computation burden. We can mitigate this by converting `memberIndex` to a sparse matrix, although you still might run into problems if your actual data has relatively few unique values that occur in very many rows. Here's one way to do this, assuming a better-case scenario:

```
memberIndex = sparse(double(memberIndex));
[rowIndex, colIndex, count] = find(triu(memberIndex.'*memberIndex, 1));
```

To explain, we perform the sparse matrix multiply, extract the upper diagonal with [`triu`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) (since the matrix will be symmetric and we only need one half, not counting the main diagonal), then find all the nonzero entries and their row and column indices. We can collect and sort this data into the results you want as follows:

```
result = sortrows([count rowIndex colIndex], 1);

result =

     1     1     5
     1     3     5
     2     2     5
```

This tells us that there is 1 value shared between rows 1 and 5 (the value 1014), 1 value shared between rows 3 and 5 (the value 301), and 2 values shared between rows 2 and 5 (the values 1016 and 6014).

There are some efficiency gains to be made by performing the matrix multiply differently, which may be necessary given your actual data, but here's the condensed version of the entire computation presented above:

```
uniqueValues = unique(vertcat(A{:}));
memberIndex = cellfun(@(c) {ismember(uniqueValues, c)}, A);
memberIndex = [memberIndex{:}];
memberIndex = sparse(double(memberIndex(sum(memberIndex, 2) > 1, :)));
[rowIndex, colIndex, count] = find(triu(memberIndex.'*memberIndex, 1));
result = sortrows([count rowIndex colIndex], 1);
```

Comment: this is GREATE :)  ... but what if the data contains more than two rows that have common values ! .. the result show only 2 rows with common values .. how to modify it so it will result in all the rows that have 7 or 8 common values !! .. but this code is PERFECT for me to start my next step ..thanks alot

Comment: @Mon aljerri: I'm not sure what you mean. Have you tried it with other data? The results will show every pair of rows that share values and how many they share. Could you post a small example of data that shows what you're asking for?

Comment: how to modify it so it will show ALL the rows that share values and how many they share .. I will post a snapshot example of data that show three rows sharing three values

Comment: @Mon aljerri: Well, that appears to *greatly* complicate things. I don't have an immediate solution for that. It'll take some thought.

Comment: thanks I really appreciate your help..I'll be waiting for your solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

The explanation you provided is far from being clear.
I understood you want the index of elements in A which have a certain amount of duplicate values (es: 2).
So in your example: [201;201;301;301;301;1012;1015], the amount of repetitions would be 3. 1 rep for 201, and 2 rep of 301. 
Is this correct? in that case that´s the code:

```
numberOfCommonElements = 2;
index = cellfun(@(mat) sum(diff(sort(mat)) == 0) == numberOfCommonElements,A);
```

Comment: I will remove all of the duplicate values, and then maybe try and use ismember to try and find rows that have matching values